# Wait for condition to be true, then continue function

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, checkbox, filter

I have a couple of checkboxes. When I check one, the other unchecks.

Every time this action happens there is a function that checks if the length of the checkboxes is equal to one.

The expected behavior is: if it's equal to one, the function must continue, if not, it must wait until it is. The thing is that the checkboxes are taking way too much time to uncheck.

So, It just ignores everything and continues...

Here's the function:

```
  function unchecking(){
    // Here I uncheck the other checkboxes when a new one gets checked
    $('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
      $('.checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });

    // Then I loop
    $.each($('.checkFiltro:checkbox:checked'), function (i, checkbox){
      // I need something like this:
      if($('.checkFiltro:checkbox:checked') < 2){
        // Continue and do another thing
      } else {
        // Wait until condition is true
      }
    });
  }
```

PS: Can't use radio. This ain't my project, and I can't change the structure of it from checkboxes to radio.

Comment: i think you want just use a radio instead of checkboxes, you discribe behavior for a radio-button

Comment: What do you mean "the checkboxes are taking way too much time to uncheck. "? this should be instantaneous

Comment: Oh, that's another thing. Can't use radio. This ain't my project, and I can't change the structure of it from checkboxes to radio. In the other hand, the function is happening before the checkboxes uncheck.

Comment: You need to do your loop inside the change event handler probably. Not really clear what you are needing to accomplish or where you call `unchecking()`. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: The lenght of the checkboxes must be equal to one. This happens if only one is checked, of course, but that's only the first half of the function. The second half must wait for this condition to be true to continue. But the function just ends without waiting.

Comment: Where and how do you call this function? If you run that function the checkboxes won't reset until the next time one is changed

Comment: If you attach a `change` listener to both the checkboxes your function will run each time the state of either checkbox changes. In that handler, you can do your test for `.prop(checked)` to see how many are checked. If it's two, run your other code. There is no need to "wait" — your code to test how many are checked will run every time any checkbox changes state.

Comment: Even if the checkboxes were created dynamically using angular?

Comment: Using angular? WHAT??? This code doesn't belong in angular app. Use angular events and work through your data model to do whatever it is your a trying to do (which is still not clear)

Comment: Told you so. Not my app. I have to work with this even if I don't like it. No need for shouting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented - you don't need to "wait" until the condition is true (that exactly one checkbox is checked). You can test that condition each time the state of any checkbox is changed.

This snippet demonstrates doing that - verbosely telling you in the console what's going on. You will see it say *"Run the rest of the code"* whenever there is exactly one checkbox checked.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(e) {
  console.log('\nchanged: ' + this.name + ' is checked: ' + this.checked);

  let allChecked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');

  console.log('number of boxes checked = ' + allChecked.length);
  console.log('now unchecking any other checked boxes');

  $('input[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  let nowChecked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  
  console.log('number of boxes now checked = ' + nowChecked.length);
  
  if (nowChecked.length === 1) {
    console.log("Run the rest of the code; here, or call a function")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Instructions, other controls, whatever
</div>
<div>
  <label for="box1">Box 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="box1" name="box1">
  <label for="box2">Box 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="box2" name="box2">
</div>
<div>
  More stuff following the checkboxes
</div>
```

However ... there will only ever be either zero or one box checked - never two - because of unchecking the other box when one gets checked. (Well I suppose there could be initially be two if both were already checked when your code started running)

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/uLbys0ak/) with the "un-check" line commented out where you can see what happens with 0, 1, or 2 boxes checked.

Comment: Thanks! I found a way to make it work with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is basically that your function is returning before all the data has arrived that you want to evaluate.

You can wait for a result by employing a timer structure.

```
function unchecking(){

    $('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
      $('.checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });

    var waitInterval = setInterval(function(){
        var count = 0 ;
         $.each($('.checkFiltro:checkbox:checked'), function (i, checkbox){
            count++;
         });
        if(count > 2){
            clearInterval(this);
            //do stuff here
        }
        //the interval will continue to ask for the no of checked boxes until it gets cleared at the if statement
    },0);

}
```

Ps. I have not tested this code, let me know if it does not do what I believe it will do, then I will fix and resend :)

Comment: This is attempting to solve an XY Problem and is really ugly